# function that checks valid words with certain letters, loop functions

Tags: python, while-loop

Hello I am trying to create a function that will retrieve a word of any length and combination of the six letters such as odd, Pow. I want the function to see if the word is valid. If it is not I then want the person to type a new word in and then check that word to see if it is valid. If it is not I want to continue the loop until the word contains only the six letters. Thank you.

```
accepeted_letters = "U", "P", "D", "O", "W", "N"
user_input_uppercase = str(input("Select one or more of each 
letter to be displated [U, P, D, O, W, N], Thank you ")).upper()
user_input_string = str(user_input_uppercase).replace(" ", "")

def valid():
    global accepeted_letters, user_input_string
    while user_input_string[0] not in accepeted_letters:
        user_input_uppercase = input("Please Enter one or more 
of the following letters: [U, P, D, O, W, N]").upper()
    if user_input_uppercase in accepeted_letters:
        pass 

valid()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prompt for input in a loop, and either `break` the loop or `return` the value from your function when the condition is met.  An easy way to test your valid letter condition is to turn the user's input into a `set` and then check to see if it's a subset of the valid letters.

```
valid_letters = "UPDOWN"

def get_valid_letters():
    while True:
        user_letters = input(
            "Select one or more of each letter: ["
            + ", ".join(valid_letters)
            + "], Thank you "
        ).upper().replace(" ", "")
        if set(user_letters).issubset(valid_letters):
            return user_letters

print(get_valid_letters(), "is valid!")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was literally the first function in the code.